# dynamically created HTML content & Google search robots

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

What is the **right way** to create large site with **PHP template**, that is creating each article from variables defined in **MySql**?If i create for example html page after click on specific product, will be Google able get this document to show product **like this?**

[image]

And if this is possible, what is best structure for this?

**I noticed somebody is using :**

example.php?id=33

**and somebody is using sentence like this :**

example/properties/property-name

**Id like to use second option, so what is the best way to do this?**
So far im able to get data from MySql and get it as variable to php.

**Im sorry, because this is probably a stupid question, but HTML that will be created is just virtual thing or its a physical file on server?**

I know pretty well HTML, JS and little bit of PHP, but all my projects was small sites, that was hardcoded, so thanks for consideration.

Comment: I dont think so, that question is not providing info about relationships between PHP generated content and Google SEO

Comment: First you should have chosen SEO as tag for this question. 2nd your question is not clear. what is that you want.? do you want a sample code to find product by property-name. or you just want confirmation that its better way?

Comment: From SEO perspective obviously property-name in URL will add more weightage to it.

Comment: Ill be happy with sample code, but thats not a point.I just need to know, if Google crawlers can recognize html page with product, thats not exist,before some action(click) on the product happens and generate this HTML in PHP

Comment: ok so please update your question. make it short and to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google **will not crawl, to unknown links**.   it  can only crawl to all links which can be traveled from your home page. or links that other sites are pointing to your site.

The link could be either **`<a/>`** tag or even a dropdown somewhere in your page should be ok. but not autocomplete or search box.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Google will search all link tags and download its content for Indexing?

Comment: Ok thanks, i was slightly confused by this.